Return Value Empty When Searching with Milvus
I was attempting to create a Milvus collection using this function below
def __generate_collection(self):
    if self.collection_name not in self.milvusClient.list_collections():
        schema = MilvusClient.create_schema(auto_id=True, enable_dynamic_field=True, primary_field="id")

        schema.add_field(field_name="id", datatype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
        schema.add_field(field_name="source", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50000)
        schema.add_field(field_name="embeddings", datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=self.truncate_dim)

        index_params = MilvusClient.prepare_index_params()

        index_params.add_index(field_name="id", index_type="STL_SORT")
        index_params.add_index(
            field_name="embeddings",
            index_type="IVF_FLAT",
            metric_type="L2",
            params={"nlist": 1024},
        )

        self.milvusClient.create_collection(
            collection_name=self.collection_name, schema=schema, index_params=index_params
        )

I then proceeded to inserting data into the collection with the code shown below
entities = [
    {"source": "hello", "embeddings": [1,2,3,4, etc..]}
]
insert_result = self.milvusClient.insert(collection_name=self.collection_name, data=entities)
print(insert_result)

#outputs {'insert_count': 1, 'ids': [450065725884255501], 'cost': 0}

Based on the outputs, the insertion of data into the collection seems successful. However, nothing is being returned when I tried to search using Milvus.
def search_and_query(
    self,
    search_vectors: list,
    search_field: str = "embeddings",
    search_params={"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 10}},
    vector_search_limit=10,
):
    result = self.milvusClient.search(
        collection_name=self.collection_name,
        data=search_vectors,
        search_params=search_params,
        anns_field=search_field,
        limit=vector_search_limit,
        output_fields=["source"],
    )
        
    print(result)
    return result

# output: data: ['[]'] , extra_info: {'cost': 0}

I am confused what could cause the problem. Can anyone please take a look for me?

A potential root cause would be your "embeddings" in your collection or search_vectors has invalid element to compute the distance.
Here's a simplified example (disclaimer: I am running it on local and my index_type is "FLAT"):

For vector_for_db and vector_for_query pair with big distance search returned the inserted record as expected
When I put some pair L2 distance results nan: e.g. vector_for_query=[1, 2, 3, float("nan")] it returned no results.

Thus I suspect this would be one potential root cause.
from pymilvus import (
    MilvusClient,
    DataType
)


def test_search(vector_for_db, vector_for_query):
    truncate_dim = 4
    collection_name = "test"
    vector_field_name = "embeddings"

    client = MilvusClient("test.db")
    schema = client.create_schema(auto_id=True, enable_dynamic_field=True, primary_field="id")
    
    schema.add_field(field_name="id", datatype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
    schema.add_field(field_name="source", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50000)
    schema.add_field(field_name=vector_field_name, datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=truncate_dim)
    
    index_params = client.prepare_index_params()
    index_params.add_index(
        field_name=vector_field_name,
        index_type="FLAT",
        metric_type="L2",
        params={"nlist": 1024}
    )
    
    if client.has_collection(collection_name=collection_name):
        client.drop_collection(collection_name=collection_name)
    client.create_collection(
        collection_name=collection_name, schema=schema, index_params=index_params
    )
    entities = [
        {"source": "hello", vector_field_name: vector_for_db}
    ]
    insert_result = client.insert(collection_name=collection_name, data=entities)
    
    return client.search(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        data=[vector_for_query],
        search_params={"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 10}},
        anns_field=vector_field_name,
        limit=10,
        output_fields=["source"],
    )

print(test_search([1, 2, 3, 4], [1e10, 1e10, 1e10, 1e10])) # Returns the inserted record
print(test_search([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, float("nan")])) # Results in 0 search results

